# Vue-socket.io vuex store integration

Tags: socket.io, vue.js

I have my store defined in ./store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    ...
});
```

and want to set up vue-socket.io in my main.js:

```
import { MyVuexStore } from './store.js'

Vue.use(VueSocketio, 'http://localhost:5000', MyVuexStore);
```

However, since the store has no name, I cannot import it and pass it to the VueSocketio:

> 62:46-57 "export 'MyVuexStore' was not found in './store.js'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you use 'export default', you don't import with curley's.
Try

```
import MyVuexStore from './store.js'
```

or change the export to be

```
export const MyVuexStore = new Vuex.Store({
```